# How to run query on multiple selected checkboxes?

Tags: php

I have multiple checkboxes (don't know how much, will print dynamically). I am using the following code to check how much boxes are selected.

```
<form action="#" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="C/C++"><label>C/C++</label><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="Java"><label>Java</label><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="PHP"><label>PHP</label><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>



<?php
    include ("include/connection.php");

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if(!empty($_POST['check_list']))
    {
        foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected)
        {

            $query = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO table (field) VALUES ('$selected')");

            if($query)
            {
                echo "Query done for ". $selected . "<br>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "problem". mysqli_error();
            }

        }
    }
}
?>
```

Now the question is I want to run a query on each one by one. How can I do it in PHP? using while loop, for loop or anyother method?

Comment: you already are looping it each using `foreach`

Comment: `foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected){  // RUN A QUERY  }`

Comment: @roullie but it's not working properly for MySQLi query

Comment: Then show code for mysqli query.

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 if(!empty($_POST['check_list']))
 {
  foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected)
  {
   
   $query = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO table (field) VALUES ('$selected')");
   
   if($query)
   {
    echo "Query done for ". $selected . "<br>";
   }
   else
   {
    echo "problem". mysqli_query();
   }
   
  }
 }
}`

Comment: Edit your question, put your code there. And there's `mysqli_error` not a `mysqli_query`.

Comment: sorry that typo mistake.

Comment: i edit the question, can you tell me the problem now?

Comment: Do you have error message with `problem` or what?

Comment: `Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in F:\wamp\www\mediaHype\check.php on line 30` I am geeting this error

Comment: Do you read manual for `mysqli_error`? Or I should do this for you?

Comment: thank  you problem solved :P